# Query Help - Where Not Exists?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, not-exists, appian

I only want to return managers who have all active accounts. In this case I am looking to return jane and her three accounts and rows of data.

```
select *
from [Table1] t1 
left join [Table2] t2 
on t1.account = t2.account 
where lower(t1.flag)='y' 
and not exists (select 1 from [Table1] tt1 where tt1.account=t1.account and tti.flag in ('NULL','n'))
```

[image: sample data]

My excepted return needs to be:
[Expected Return Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPNjf.png)

Comment: What are the data in the source tables?

Comment: The NULL in the data is a string `'NULL'` or an empty value?

Comment: String NULL unfortunately @mik

Comment: That is why I am using 'NULL' @mik

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to collate the counts for each manager, then filter

```
select t.account, t.flag, t.manager from (
    select *, Count(*) over (partition by manager) cnt,
      Sum(case when flag='y' then 1 end) over(partition by manager) f
    from t
)t
where cnt=f
```